# A web application for corporate team blog

Tags: web-apps, self-hosted, blog

I'm looking for a free (open-source is desirable) web application software which is suitable for having internal team blog - one that can be hosted locally and used for sharing information and discussions among a medium-sized distributed team.

Ideally it would have some customizable and flexible permission model.

It turns out that finding software of this kind is a surprisingly tricky task to achieve. Even if we'll consider proprietary software as well it looks like there's no that much of solutions available on the market (for instance, Blogin).

Comment: What blogging features do you need? What do you mean with "flexible permission model"? -- Did you find software that you ruled out? For example, what about WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

have you considered an **intranet** based wordpress application?

There's a tutorial on it on [lynda.com](https://www.lynda.com/WordPerfect-tutorials/WordPress-Creating-Intranet-Website/560067-2.html?srchtrk=index%3a1%0alinktypeid%3a2%0aq%3aintranet+wordpress%0apage%3a1%0as%3arelevance%0asa%3atrue%0aproducttypeid%3a2)